# I have a trigger to execute a SP when one column is updated. If I add an insert operation it runs the SP for any changes to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am looking to get the SP run only when the Instructions column has something added or altered.
This code works for updating of the Instructions column

```
AFTER Update

AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT on
    if update ([Instructions])
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ID INT
            SELECT  @ID = (SELECT [ID] FROM inserted)
            EXEC [dbo].[Gem_AddNoteToDelivery] @ID 
    
        END 

END

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DeliveryNote] ENABLE TRIGGER [Gemini_DeliveryNote_AddNote]
GO
```

My Stored Procedure is this

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Gem_AddNoteToDelivery] 

   @ID INT output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


 
    DECLARE @DInst VARCHAR (4000)
    DECLARE @DELNN VARCHAR (32)

    Select  @Dinst = [Instructions],
            @DELNN = [DelNoteNumber]


    FROM [dbo].[DeliveryNote] WHERE [id]=@ID 


 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Notes]
                    --([UserID],[OperatorID],[UserName],[DateDB],[ModuleType],[RecordID],[RecordNo],[Flags],[Details],[Priority],[NotesType])
                VALUES
                   (115,0,'Automation',getdate(),4,@ID,@DELNN,
                   0x0000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,@DInst,1,Null) 


END

GO
```

If I alter the Trigger to read

```
AFTER Update,Insert
```

then the SP runs for updates to all columns not just the Instructions one.
The database is not mine so I am unable to alter tables.

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: Your trigger is broken, `Inserted` can contain 0-N rows, not just one, so you need to handle it using a set based approach.

Comment: I don't think you have read the documentation for `UPDATE` - update means that column was included in the update or importantly when you add `insert` the `INSERT` statement. It doesn't mean the data changed. And of course with an `INSERT` every column is included.

Comment: When an `UPDATE` occurs you want to check the new data (`Inserted`) against the old data (`DELETED`) to tell whether its changed or not. For an `INSERT` the data is new, so that always counts as changed.

Comment: _The database is not mine so I am unable to alter tables_ A trigger is defined as a schema change and is likely to violate your license. Given your attempt, this is not a wise decision.